# How can I combine 2D histograms of 3 factors on the same plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, 2d, legend, density-plot

I am trying to plot 2D histograms of 3 factors on the same plot however I can't make it work. The histograms are plotted but for some reason the color of the second factor appears on the 2d histogram of the 3rd factor and the opposite. In addition, not matter what I have tried, only the legends of 2 of the objects appear on the final graph. Any ideas???

Here is my code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gtable)


# plot with red fill

AmAs <-read.csv("AmAs.csv", header = TRUE)
p1 <- ggplot(data = AmAs, aes(x, y, color = as.factor(Group))) +
stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..), alpha = 0.3, geom = "polygon") +
scale_fill_continuous(low = "grey", high = "red", space = "Lab",name="And")+
scale_colour_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
theme_classic()


# plot with blue fill

p2 <- ggplot(data = AmAs, aes(x, y, color = as.factor(Group))) +
stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..), alpha = 0.3, geom = "polygon") +
scale_fill_continuous(low = "grey", high = "blue",space="Lab",name="Gyn") +
scale_colour_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
theme_classic()


# plot with orange fill

p3 <- ggplot(data = AmAs, aes(x, y, color = as.factor(Group))) +
stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..), alpha = 0.3, geom = "polygon") +
scale_fill_continuous(low="grey",high="orange",space="Lab", name = "Fer") +
scale_colour_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
theme_classic()



# grab plot data

pp1 <- ggplot_build(p1)
pp2 <- ggplot_build(p2)$data[[1]]
pp3<- ggplot_build(p3)$data[[1]]



# replace red fill colours in pp1 with blue colours from pp2 when group is 2

pp1$data[[1]]$fill[grep(pattern="^2",pp2$group)]<-pp2$fill[grep(pattern="^2",  pp2$group)]
pp1$data[[1]]$fill[grep(pattern = "^3", pp3$group)] <- pp3$fill[grep(pattern = "^3", pp3$group)]



# build plot grobs

grob1 <- ggplot_gtable(pp1)
grob2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)
grob3 <- ggplotGrob(p3)



# build legend grobs

leg1 <- gtable_filter(grob1, "guide-box") 
leg2 <- gtable_filter(grob2, "guide-box")
leg3 <- gtable_filter(grob3, "guide-box")
leg <- gtable:::rbind_gtable(leg1[["grobs"]][[1]],  leg2[["grobs"]][[1]], "first")



# replace legend in 'red' plot


grob1$grobs[grob1$layout$name == "guide-box"][[1]] <- leg



# plot

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(grob1)
```

Comment: A) I don't really know what a "2d histogram" is supposed to look like. B) You also have no data. (:The reason for my close vote which I would reverse if you corrected that error.) A histogram has discrete intervals and the area of the bars is proportional to the integrals across the interval. How were you going to do that in 2 dimensions? The ggplot package doesn't provide very much in the way of pseudo-3d effects. It's authors hate the Excel "2d historgrams"